# In what cases will I get the value "undefined" after this command ga((t) => {console.log(t)})

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

In the client site, I need a trigger in `ga` send some data.

If I use this method: 
`ga((t) => {console.log(t)})`, I getting `undefined`
 
but if I use:
 
`window.ga.getAll()`, I see one tracker.

What are the reasons for this?

Thanks

Comment: This is my client site:
https://www.karamba.com/

Answer (score 0):

From https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/command-queue-reference

A callback function to be invoked when the library is fully loaded and ready to be interacted with. The function is invoked with the default tracker object as it first argument. If no default tracker has been created, the first argument is undefined.

It seems like the tracker you have defined is not a "default" tracker

Comment: Yes, I see this text, but if I did not create default tracker, this method: 
`window.ga.getAll()`
return an empty array.

in my cays I see one tracker in array

Comment: Can you post your ga('create'...) , obfuscated of course?

Comment: `ga('create', 'UA-13333317-1', 'auto', 'myTracker');`

But I don't know how client do this

Comment: I said obfuscated! You should delete your comment so people don't have your tracker id.

Comment: Again, the documentation explicitly gives the example you are using down to the "myTracker" and shows that that results in no *default* tracker because it is a *named* tracker